# When to use JOIN and when not to in LINQ to entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I am new to Linq and I have seen that if there are multiple entities, some use the multiple FROM syntax like this:

```
from h in db.Hubs   
from ch in h.CityHubs where ch.Cities.CityID == 1 
select
```

and some use the explicity join syntax.

```
from h in db.Hubs
join ch in da.CityHubs on h.CityId equals ch.CityId
select
```

If I am using Linq to entities, which one should I use? If I were to use Linq to objects, which one should I use?

Answer (score 2):

As a rule, in Entity Framework, if you have a proper model and properly set up navigation properties for foreign keys, you should almost never use `join` - instead you access your navigational property directly and EF will generate the necessary `join` in the SQL code for you. I recommend taking a look at @Craig Stuntz's [blogpost](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/) regarding this issue.
Regarding Linq-to-objects, however, it depends on the particular query you are writing.